# Unity3D call function from another script (Unityscript)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've looked up similar questions and responses and still have not been able to get this to work.

LessonRightButton.js

```
//#pragma strict
public var audio1 : AudioPlayback;

function OnClick(){
        var findAudioSource = GameObject.Find("AudioPlaybackButton");
        var audio1:AudioPlayback = findAudioSource.GetComponent(AudioPlayback);
        audio1.woo(); //  THIS IS LINE 50 IN THE ERROR
}
```

AudioPlayback.js

```
//#pragma strict

function woo(){
    Debug.Log("wooooooooooooooo");
}
```

I get this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object LessonRightButton.OnClick () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/LessonRightButton.js:50)

I'm trying to call the woo function from a different script.
These scripts are shortened for the purpose of ease of reading. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have no AudioPlayback attached on that AudioPlaybackButton object.

Either add one manually or by code:

```
function OnClick(){
        var findAudioSource = GameObject.Find("AudioPlaybackButton");
        var audio1:AudioPlayback = findAudioSource.GetComponent(AudioPlayback);
        if(audio1 == null){
            audio1 = findAudioSource.AddComponent(AudioPlayback);
        }
        audio1.woo();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Messing around with your solution, I realized that I set the wrong GameObject. The GameObject that I needed to set it to was "AudioPlayback" which already had an AudioSource assigned to it, not "AudioPlaybackButton" :-)